# Shell Script Create Directory if does Not Exist

Tags: bash

I am creating application home directory if does not exist, using below script, after creating directory i need mount the file system to install software to run the application. can you please some one help me out how to perform this action.

```
APP_HOME=/opt/app
if [[ ! -e $APP_HOME ]]; then
    mkdir -p $APP_HOME
    echo "$APP_HOME" directory created!
else
    echo "$APP_HOME" directory does not exist!
fi
```

Comment: Why do you say "does not exist" when it already exists?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Can you say what is the expected result, and what you get instead?

Comment: You don't need to check the existence before creating it with `-p`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost right. There's no need for the else clause. I like to use -p to create missing parents. Also I use -d to ensure a file doesn't exist with the same name.

```
directory=/var/log/my/directory
if [ ! -d $directory ]; then
echo "directory doesn't exist"
mkdir -p $directory
fi
```

Comment: The questions is how to mount the directory

Answer (score -1):

I wouldn't bother checking.  Mkdir doesn't return errors if the directory is already there.  Just run it once before the mount command.  If you're worried about the two commands running too closely together so that mount still complains about no directory, just use sleep to give yourself a 0.5 second delay between them.

```
#!/bin/sh

APP_HOME=/opt/app
mkdir -p "${APP_HOME}"
sleep 0.5
mount /dev/sda5 "${APP_HOME}"
```

Comment: touch file; mkdir -p file